# how to fix "AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find_element_class_name''?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main"))
    )
    articles = main.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")
    for article in articles:
        header = article.find_element_class_name("entry-title")
        print(header.text)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

It shows the error as:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'find_element_class_name'
```

Comment: it should be `find_elements_by_class_name("content")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `find_element_by_class_name` and `find_elements_by_class_name` for a list of elements with the given class name

Comment: Please don't answer the duplicate questions, flag them instead. Please see [**how should duplicate questions be handled**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled)